# Answer deleted as spam/offensive, doesn't seem to be

Tags: discussion

I just noticed a [Community-locked-and-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36459421/revisions) that is labeled as "This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown".

The answer is completely off-base and worthy of downvoting, but it feels to me like an enormous stretch to consider it "spam or offensive". (The OP wanted an R-based solution for not downloading a file if it was already present on disk; the answer suggests using HttpResponse to see if there's anything available at the URL.)

- Any ideas on what's up with this? (could there be further information I'm not seeing, e.g. an offensive-but-now-deleted comment exchange?)
- Is this just some kind of mislabeling, i.e. it was deleted for some other reason but the wrong explanation is being displayed?
- Does having a question deleted in this way give any special penalties to the answerer (in which case this would seem unfair/grounds for review)?

Comment: Probably the link at the bottom which reeks of spam.

Comment: I can't see it. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, that explains it. I missed that ...

Comment: @Laurel Here http://i.stack.imgur.com/fMhqC.png

Comment: Since I now realize that the main problem was that I overlooked the spam-link at the bottom, are there suggestions about what to do with this question? There are 3 close votes due to "off topic" (which seems weird - a better close reason would something like the "simple typographical error or other unreproducible issue" answer on SO). As of now there are 11 up- and 10 downvotes ... I could edit the question (including the screenshot) and explain my thinko, but that feels like editing the answer into the question. Or I'm happy to delete if that's suggested.

Comment: @BenBolker, you should edit-in links to "Max Growth" products and wait for us to flag it as spam. :)  Otherwise, it's a useful question and answers and comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am one of the people who flagged that answers as spam.  It was reported in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) by the spam detecting bot [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) created by the [Charcoal Team](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE)

I reviewed it and the link at the bottom has nothing to do with the question and we should not edit spam links out of an answer.  The only recourse is to spam flag.

Comment: Also complete nonsense even without the link, but the link is the dead giveaway as to the intent.

Comment: @Shog9 True but without the link it is VLQ or NAA not spam.

Comment: Correct, @Nathan. Just noting that editing out the link doesn't significantly improve the answer, even if that wasn't discouraged.

Comment: Reads like project spam. SO users have a pretty good record detecting crap like this without the help of a bot.  Well, other than the OP :)  This kind of organized witch hunting is very creepy.

Comment: @HansPassant I just wanted to detail how I found it and what was going on. :)

Comment: I know, we see personal testimonials like that on midnight TV.

Comment: The value of stuff like SmokeDetector isn't so much that this stuff wouldn't get caught otherwise, @Hans... It's that it might not get caught as quickly. Two minutes after that answer was deleted, the same user tried to post on another question... But was blocked by the system since his previous answer had been identified as spam. This is a minor convenience on Stack Overflow, but a huge boon to other sites where a delay might mean dozens of such answers waiting for a moderator to wake up.

Comment: ...uh, guys? Piling votes on that message doesn't make you look like LESS of a cabal...

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, you can totally trust us ... :(

Comment: @Shog9, Closing the circle: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28809279#28809279  :D

Comment: @Shog9 Well certainly not when you frame the situation that way :-P

Comment: @Shog9 Who is to say that we are not? *sinister cackle*

Comment: @Shog9 Jokes aside, Smokey is a huge amount of power to wield for a person. A report on there that is validated by a privileged user usually gets destroyed in a matter of seconds. Wether or not thats a good thing or not, thats for you to decide....

Comment: Which is why I keep a sharp eye on it, @Magisch. Well, that and the opportunity for meta commentary.